# Добавить тег конверсии Google Adwords в JS

Tags: google-adwords

Добрый день!

Такой проблема. Есть html-сайт, хочу добавить в него тег конверсий от Google Adwords.

Код вставлен в html-шаблон.

```js
<!-- Google Code for Conversion Page
In your html page, add the snippet and call
goog_report_conversion when someone clicks on the
chosen link or button. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  goog_snippet_vars = function() {
    var w = window;
    w.google_conversion_id = XXXXXXX;
    w.google_conversion_label = "rsc4CMjtuGUQmoOCwwM";
    w.google_remarketing_only = false;
  }
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
  goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
    goog_snippet_vars();
    window.google_conversion_format = "3";
    var opt = new Object();
    opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
  var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
  if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
    conv_handler(opt);
  }
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Вызов функции осуществлялся по клику:

```html
<input class="button-order" name="submit" value="Отправить заказ" type="submit" onclick="goog_report_conversion (); return true;">
```

Работает исправно. Но задача в следующем, вызвать эту функцию в файле main.JS. 
Клик по кнопке не дает полную картинку конверсии, поэтому задача вставить вызов этой функции после или перед выводом сообщения об успешном заказе.
В main.JS есть функция:

```js
function orderBack() {

$('<div class="bg-shadow"><div class="info-message"><b>Спасибо за заказ!</b> В ближайшее время с Вами свяжется менеджер для уточнения делателей по заказу<div class="close-popup"><i class="ic-close"></i></div></div></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.case_more');  
                          
}
```

Прошу помощи, в JS полный чайник :(
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй использовать Google Tag Manager.
Создай событие, которое будет срабатывать по клику или при редиректе на определённую страницу. Или при отрисовке какого-нибудь класса.

**UPD**

Там даже можно связать аккаунт Tag Manager с аккаунтом Adwords и отслеживать ID товаров и всё остальное, что может отслеживать Remarketing Tag. Даже гугл аналитику можно прикрутить.

**UPD2**

Если всё-таки надо так отслеживать, вставь просто этот код в конце  в начале  твоего сайта.